# load image from camera intent issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using `glide` library to load images taken by a camera into an `imageview`.

I have tested my app on 3 different devices

- Samsung Galaxy Note 4(API 23)
- Motorola G4(API 24)
- Samsung Galaxy S6(API 24).

The image is loaded successfully in the first two devices, but it fails in the third device with error:

> Load failed for content://com.tsiro.dogvip.provider/p/20170613_215541
>   with size [324x324]; exception Glide produces).
>   class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: 
>   Failed to load resource
>   Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
>   Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
>   Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
>   Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory

code is inside a Fragment

```
private File output;

private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
        "com.tsiro.dogvip.EXTRA_FILENAME";
private static final String FILENAME="cameraimage.jpeg";
private static final String PHOTOS="photos";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mView == null) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.owner_frgmt, container, false);
        mView = mBinding.getRoot();
    }
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mCommonUtls = new CommonUtls(getActivity());
    mOwnerFrgmtViewModel = new OwnerViewModel(MyPetsRequestManager.getInstance());

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }
}

private void initializePickProfilePhotoDialog() {
   String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            output=new File(new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), timeStamp);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", output);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getActivity().getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);
                intent.setClipData(clip);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            else {
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList= getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    getActivity().grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
            Log.e(debugTag, intent.getData()+"");

            startActivityForResult(intent, AppConfig.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

}


  @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == AppConfig.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI || requestCode == AppConfig.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri;
            boolean cameraImg = false;
            if (requestCode == AppConfig.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", output);
                cameraImg = true;
            } else {
                uri = data.getData();
            }
            if (mCommonUtls.isImageSizeValid(uri, cameraImg, output)) {
                setUserProfileImg(uri);
            } else {
                ((MyPetsActivity)getActivity()).showSnackBar(R.style.SnackBarSingleLine, getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_image_size));
            }
        }
    }
}


private void setUserProfileImg(final Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null) {
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(uri)
                .transition(withCrossFade())
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .circleCrop())
                .into(mBinding.profileImgv);
    }
}
```

Please if anyone could help me...it's an urgent.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exception that glides produces? `exception Glide produces` There's more?

Comment: i updated my question..

Comment: Please update your question and indicate where this code lives - Activity? FragmentActivity? Fragment? Class?

Comment: just updated my friend

Comment: I deleted my old answer, thought it was `getActivity()` being `null` related. What I recommend is you add exception handling to your code to pinpoint the issue. You can be certain the path is bad because the file can't be found and you rely on `Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", output);`. I believe the problem lies there.